# Updates to the site

Tags: discussion, design

My name is Stéphane and I'm a designer at Stack Exchange, you may have noticed some updates to the design lately.

The updates are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework (the code which display the design).

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

As you can see, the layout of the header section was also updated for a better use of the space while maintaining the old look and feel. The centered design was made for the old logo ("Travel [mark] answers"). We can now display more questions without scrolling.

**But more importantly, it gives you access to [the new profile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: So this is mayhem all *your* fault?! :D All jokes aside, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Not necessarily a 'bug' but a badly needed UX feature. A button docked to the bottom right of the screen that jumps your view to the top of the page.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this counts as a bug - I use a travel map from traveltip on my
profile and as you can see I can scroll only vertical but not horizontal.

[image: bug screenshot]

Comment: We don't want to allow vertical scrolling in this section because the vertical scrollbar is really against the design, images should be resized to the size of the description box (unchanged since the beginning).

Answer (score 4):

Not really a design issue, but the Informed badge cannot be earned on meta, as we don't have a meta tour page, but the badge is listed on my new profile.

[image: bug screenshot]

Comment: Regarding profile related bugs/feedback, we created a [dedicated post on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253450/new-profile-pages-are-out-bugs-and-feedback-master-list)

Comment: @StéphaneMartin unfortunately the post is locked now

Comment: We're aware of the "informed" issue, we'll work on it as soon as we can and we'll push a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

The colour choices for normal links and visited links in the hot network questions is counter-intuitive, as visited links get emphasised and not de-emphasised:

[image]

(I had the same issue on [Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2599/36423).)